# Difference between require('myModule') and require(['myModule'])

Tags: asp.net, node.js, module, requirejs

What's the difference between `require('myModule')` 
and `require(['myModule'])` ?

I am using require 2.x.x version in my Asp.Net MVC project but when I try using some Node modules that make use of

```
require('myModule')
```

like syntax, the calls fail.
I guess this is pertains to nodejs environment. If true how to make these calls work in other web apps that are non Node based?

Comment: require(['myModule', 'myModule2'])  is an array off modules

Comment: Not clear if you're using NodeJS or RequireJS, include a bigger code sample that reproduces the problem. If you're using RequireJS, then looks like you'd benefit from reading [the official documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html).

Comment: @kryger I am not using NodeJS but its most modules are also used outside of NodeJS in any web application as it is js based. I am giving you examples of ElementalUI, classNames, Rackt Model which I tried to use in my normal web application by inclusion of these files along with latest requireJS in page header but it did not work out. It always complains something like requireJS syntax error in firebug.